# Android OnLocationChanged never being called

Tags: android

I have the following code - 
`enter code here`
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Locations;
    using Android.Bluetooth;

```
namespace GetCurrentLocation
{
    [Activity(Label = "Get Current Location", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity, ILocationListener
    {
        LocationManager _locMgr ;
        String oBestProvider;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            _locMgr = GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.UI);
            StringBuilder strLocations = new StringBuilder();
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGetLocation);
            int i;
            var locationText =
                FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLocation);

                Android.Locations.Location oLocation;

            oLocation = _locMgr.GetLastKnownLocation (Context.LocationService);
            IList<String> oLocationProviders = _locMgr.GetProviders(true);

            //Location location;
            button.Click += delegate {
                if(oLocationProviders != null)
                    {

                _locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(oLocationProviders[0], 2000, 1, this);
                _locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(oLocationProviders[1], 2000, 1, this);


                    }
                    else{

                    locationText.Text ="No Provider Found";
                    }

            };

        }



        protected override void OnResume() {
            base.OnResume();

        }

        protected override void OnPause() {
            base.OnPause ();
            _locMgr.RemoveUpdates(this);
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged (Location location)
        {

            var locationText =
                   FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtLocation);
            if (location != null) {
                locationText.Text = String.Format ("Latitude = {0}, Longitude = {1}",
                   location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
            }
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {

        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried using GetBestProvider/ GetProviders/ RequestLocationUpdates/ GetLastKnownLocation. I am not able to proceed. Can somebody please guide me why my OnLocationUpdates never gets called. I am also not able to use the Override keyword on this function even though the class Activity is implementing the ILocationListener interface. Please help.....
And also just for your info, I am trying to run this code on the trial version Emulator AVD For Nexus 5 by Google.

Comment: I think you meant Nexus 4 / Nexus S. **Nexus 5** is not release yet. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on the emulator then onLocationChanged will never get called until and unless you supply the location from DDMS. From DDMS you need to give latitude and longitude so it will call desired method.

please check the code on real device in open area.

Comment: I had downloaded my trial version from the Xamarin Store where it says the free version will provide a Xamarin studio that is MonoDevelop and the ability to Deploy to Device. store.xamarin.com..... Can't I use the ability to deploy to device instead of buying the complete Monodevelop.

Comment: use fake gps application from play store